# Array defined outside of function not being populated after awaiting an async call

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following code where in the `getStuff` function I'm making an external async call and storing the result in `result`. From there I'm looping over `result.Content.Ids` and pushing the Ids in `myArray`.

When `getStuff()` gets called in `run()`, further down the code I need to access `myStuff` array but if I console.log it out, it shows up as empty.

```
const myArray = [];

const getStuff = async (val) => {
    const other = {}

    if(val) other.newestVal = val;

    const result = await someCall(other);

    result.Content.Ids.forEach((id) => myArray.push(id));

    if (result.AFieldExists) {
        getStuff(result.newVal)
    }
}

const run = async () => {
    await getStuff();

    // other code below that uses myArray
    // but its empty when I log it
}

run();
```

I'd have expected `myArray` to be populated since I'm awaiting `getStuff()` in `run()`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/qusumib/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: try to await `getStuff()` inside the recursive call too

Comment: @VLAZ that's probably because your code example doesn't makes a recursive call.

Comment: @Yousaf it was supposed to be a gentle reminder that there is no [mcve] in the post. But yes, you're right. To be clear "this code doesn't work" with no indication *how* it should work and *when* it fails, are *more* work for us to answer and shouldn't be. Given how easy is to mock the `someCall` (see snippet) there is really no reason to withhold reproduction steps from us.

Answer (score 4):

Your recursive call:

```
if (result.AFieldExists) {
    getStuff(result.newVal)
}
```

is incorrect, since you're not waiting for the result - only the first `getStuff` call will be waited for. You need:

```
const getStuff = async (val) => {
    const other = {}

    if(val) other.newestVal = val;

    const result = await someCall(other);

    result.Content.Ids.forEach((id) => myArray.push(id));

    if (result.AFieldExists) {
        return getStuff(result.newVal)
    }
}
```

You can also clean it up a bit to avoid the ugly outer variable:

```
const getStuff = async (val, output = []) => {
    const other = {}
    if (val) other.newestVal = val;
    const result = await someCall(other);
    output.push(...result.Content.Ids);
    return result.AFieldExists
        ? getStuff(result.newVal, output)
        : output;
}

const run = async () => {
    const output = await getStuff(); // pass initial value here?
}
```

Comment: Here I don't want to return `result` though. I want to return the `output` array. Also do I need to await the getStuff recursive call too?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your `await` calls in `try{} catch(){}`,
and also your recursive call to `getStuff()` was with out the key word `await` :

```
    async function someCall() {
  return {
    Content: {Ids: [1, 2, 3]}
  }
}


const myArray = [];



const getStuff = async (val) => {
    const other = {}
    let result;
    if(val) other.newestVal = val;
try{
    result = await someCall(other);
}catch(err){
console.log('error from some call' ,err);
}
console.log(myArray)
    result.Content.Ids.forEach((id) => myArray.push(id));
console.log(myArray)

    if (result.AFieldExists) {
        try{
        await getStuff(result.newVal)
        }catch(err){
            console.log('error from get stuff in get stuff' , err);
        }
    }
}

const run = async () => {
    console.log("run")
  try{
    await getStuff();
  }catch(err){
      console.log('error' , err);
  }
    console.log("end run")
console.log(myArray)
    // other code below that uses myArray
    // but its empty when I log it
}

run();
```